# Does google app engine's "memcache.get()" return a reference or deep copy?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

Does app engine's "memcache.get()" return a reference or deep copy?

The reason I ask is because I'd like to know if I need to call memcache.set() after I've modified an object.

For example:

```
# INITALIZE
t_var = {}
t_var['foo'] = 1
memcache.set('some_key', t_var)

# LATER ON...
t_var = memcache.get('some_key')
t_var['foo'] = 2

# EVEN LATER ON...
t_var = memcache.get('some_key')
print t_var['foo']
```

Is does `print t-var['foo']` display a '1' or a '2'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objects are serialized (using `pickle` by default) before being sent to `memcached`. Thus, the objects you get back are necessarily copies. This is because `memcached` is a separate process from the Python interpreter and, furthermore, knows nothing of Python objects specifically.